# Sort points with less STL operator

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, opencv, stl

i want to sort 110 KeyPoints from openCV blob detection, from top to bottom and left to right. but sometimes it goes wrong.

```
bool sortRects(const Rect &a, const Rect &b)
{
return ( (a.x + a.y*10) < (b.x + b.y*10) );
}

   vector<Rect> convertedKeyPoints;

   for(int i = 0; i < detectedLedPositions.size(); i++)
   {
   Point2f point(detectedLedPositions[i].pt.x+1.f, detectedLedPositions[i].pt.y + 1.f);
   Rect keyPointToRect(detectedLedPositions[i].pt, point);
   convertedKeyPoints.push_back(keyPointToRect);
   }

   sort(convertedKeyPoints.begin(), convertedKeyPoints.end(), sortRects);

 for(int i = 0; i < convertedKeyPoints.size(); i++)
        {
            QPointF currentPoint(QPoint(convertedKeyPoints[i].tl().x , convertedKeyPoints[i].tl().y));
            ledPosition.push_back(currentPoint);
        }
```

This is the output from the debug console after converting the to QPointF.

```
QPointF(133, 138)
QPointF(188, 134)
QPointF(240, 134)
QPointF(290, 135)
QPointF(347, 142)
QPointF(454, 137)
QPointF(398, 144)
QPointF(507, 136)
QPointF(27, 189)
QPointF(191, 191)
**QPointF(138, 199)**
QPointF(244, 191)
QPointF(293, 194)
QPointF(345, 189)
QPointF(400, 194)
QPointF(451, 190)
QPointF(505, 192)
```

So what do i wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the three points you are having a problem with: 191 + 191 * 10 < 138 + 199 * 10 < 244 + 191 * 10.

Comment: Try a greater weighting for the y-coordinate, e.g. multiply by 1000 instead of by 10.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It will work until it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think your sort operation is assuming a.x<10, and it is not the case in your example.

Try:

```
bool sortRects(const Rect &a, const Rect &b)
{
  return a.y == b.y ? a.x < b.x : a.y < b.y;
}
```

This will sort on the Y axis first (top to bottom), and in the case both are exactly equal, will fall back to sort on the X axis (left to right).

Comment: Only thing to watch out for is floating point precision comparing equality.

Comment: Thanks guys, but no matter which factor i choose one or two points get sorted wrong.